# Automatically update Drupal core/modules for a large number of sites (with Drush)?

Tags: drush, updating

I'm the administrator of a lot of Drupal websites on different hosting providers.

Some have drush; others don't (and can't: like shared hosting).

Every time there is a Core upgrade, I spend 1 or 2 hours updating everything (I make a backup of every website before an upgrade).

Updating sites with Drush is simple, but I need to do it for every website, like :

- drush @dev up
- drush @othersite up
- and wait... wait... wait...

How can I automatically update Core (and modules) on:

- all my drush sites ? (I think : cron with bash script)
- all my non-drush sites ?

Is this safe, or do you not recommend it?

Answer (score 5):

What I would suggest, is to store all your Drupal sites in GIT repositories. With a separate branch / repo for Core and as many as necessary for /sites/*

Then you can easily do updates to cores by a simple pull. For shared hosting, pull locally, then sync by lftp to your distant hosts.

Comment: i like this method :)

Comment: I like it too ! Any doc/link out there ?

Comment: Well, we'll do a big tutorial about deployment strategies on http://adyax.com/en/tutorials next weeks. It will cover Capistrano, Drush, AEGIR, and stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

With Drush you can use

```
drush @sites up
```

To update all your sites at once.

I guess you could use drush to remotely update your non drush sites too.

Comment: don't know about "@sites" that update "all sites at once" on my webserver. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use drush command to update your site

```
drush upc --no-core
```

[More druh commands](http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-5x/pm/pm-updatecode)